# Scraping data through graphql seller query from walmart in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, graphql

I want to get the sellers information from product page from walmart website
i.e for product url -https://www.walmart.com/ip/Bigelow-Green-Tea-With-Mint-Tea-Bags-20-Count/10293196
using walmart's graphql query

```
  -H 'WM_PAGE_URL: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Yogi-Tea-Green-Tea-Blueberry-Slim-Life-Tea-Tea-Bags-16-Ct/23658492' \
  -H 'X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME: GetAllSellerOffers' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{"query":"query GetAllSellerOffers( $itemId:String\u0021 $postalAddress:PostalAddress $storeFrontIds:[StoreFrontId]){product( itemId:$itemId postalAddress:$postalAddress storeFrontIds:$storeFrontIds ){allOffers{offerId offerType availabilityStatus fulfillmentType fulfillmentBadge sellerId catalogSellerId sellerName sellerDisplayName sellerType wfsEnabled hasSellerBadge priceInfo{currentPrice{price priceString}unitPrice{price priceString}}returnPolicy{returnable freeReturns returnWindow{value unitType}}shippingOption{slaTier availabilityStatus accessTypes deliveryDate maxDeliveryDate shipPrice{price priceString}}}}}","variables":{"itemId":"10293196"}}' \
```

and below is the ruby script

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
data= {
   "query":"query GetAllSellerOffers( $itemId:String! $postalAddress:PostalAddress $storeFrontIds:[StoreFrontId]){product( itemId:$itemId postalAddress:$postalAddress storeFrontIds:$storeFrontIds ){allOffers{offerId offerType availabilityStatus fulfillmentType fulfillmentBadge sellerId catalogSellerId sellerName sellerDisplayName sellerType wfsEnabled hasSellerBadge priceInfo{currentPrice{price priceString}unitPrice{price priceString}}returnPolicy{returnable freeReturns returnWindow{value unitType}}shippingOption{slaTier availabilityStatus accessTypes deliveryDate maxDeliveryDate shipPrice{price priceString}}}}}",
   "variables":{"itemId":"10293196","affinityOverride": "default"}

}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type':'application/json',
    'WM_PAGE_URL'=><Product-URL>, 
    'X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME' => 'GetAllSellerOffers'
    }

params= {
    "affinityOverride": "default",
    "page": "1",
    "prg": "desktop",
    "itemId": "10293196",
    "fetchMarquee": "true",
    "fetchSkyline": "true",
    "fetchSbaTop": "false"}

response = HTTParty.post('https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/GetAllSellerOffers',body: data.to_json,headers: headers, params: params)
```

But this is continuously giving me response as

```
{"redirectUrl":"/blocked?url=Lw==\u0026uuid=6529c397-9090-11ec-88c9-77495141424f\u0026vid=\u0026g=b","appId":"PXu6b0qd2S","jsClientSrc":"/px/PXu6b0qd2S/init.js","firstPartyEnabled":true,"vid":"","uuid":"6529c397-9090-11ec-88c9-77495141424f","hostUrl":"/px/PXu6b0qd2S/xhr","blockScript":"/px/PXu6b0qd2S/captcha/captcha.js?a=c\u0026m=0\u0026u=6529c397-9090-11ec-88c9-77495141424f\u0026v=\u0026g=b"}
```

Comment: you're getting blocked by Cloudflare, try using a proxy server with HTTParty.